# how to detect an element which becomes visible once mouse hover is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am working on a project where the image consists of an element(view button) which becomes visible once mouse hover is performed.
I need to mouse hover on the image,thereby making the "view" button visible on that image and click on the view button.
I saw many posts regarding this issue,But didn't get an exact solution to it.
I tried using the following ,wherein it has to mouse hover the image,but this was not working out for me.
[Note:Used selenium webdriver and executed in firefox]

```js
 act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='thm_KCI-001']"))).perform();
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='thm_KCI-001']//tr[2]//button[contains(text(),'View')]"))).perform();
```

I tried using the javascript executor too, but it didn't workout for me.

```js
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('select#periodId').click();");
```

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood, couldn't this be done with plain CSS using the `:hover` pseudo-prop?

Comment: i needed to know only with xpath